# index.ctp in cakephp not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'am a beginner in cakephp and i have installed it , and i start every thing perfectly , But the problem is when i use the index.ctp which in view/Posts folder  code is

```
<?php echo $v; ?>
```

and the PostsController.php code is

class PostsController extends AppController {

```
public $name = 'Posts';

public function index(){
    $this->set('v',$this->Post->findById('all'));
    }}
```

But the php code not displays nothing

please help i have to start fast because am going to be tested to get a job

Comment: `$v` is an array, not a string, so you need to do `pr($v)` instead of the echo. Also, a sidenote, if you are going to be tested to get a job, you should probably start on how to be a master at debugging and researching first.

Answer (score 0):

findById('all') is wrong , findById(ID) is true

example => findById(2) for fetch a record of Post that Post.id is 2

i think u want fetch all Post data , so.. do this :

in your controller:

```
public function index(){
   $this->set('v',$this->Post->find('all'));
}
```

and in view:

```
foreach($v as $value){
     echo $value['FIELD_NAME'];
}
```